# GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: Exception thrown initializing deserializer *name*. Cause: *name*: columns has 110 elements while columns.types has 106

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

This error happens to me anytime I try to query the 'airports' table in my database which was created by a glue crawler I created for this purpose along with 3 other datasets. They were all csv files beforehand, and I have performed each and every step of this process already in MySQL Workbench locally before trying it out on the cloud in AWS right now and I never got any errors like this when querying my airports dataset there.

```
SELECT * FROM "runway_db_athena"."airports" limit 10;
```

Or
SELECT region FROM "runway_db_athena"."airports" limit 10;

And what I got back was:

```
GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: SerDeException thrown initializing deserializer
org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe. 
Cause: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe: columns has 110 elements while columns.types has 106 elements!
```

When as you can see in this screenshot, region is clearly a column in this table:
[image]

What can I do to be able to run queries on this table? I opened it up in Excel, hit Ctrl+Shift+RightArrow and it does only have 106 columns, I know because I also hit Ctrl+Shift+End and again, only 106 columns, so what can I do to get Athena to recognize this? I would create a table for it in Athena from scratch if it didn't have 106 columns!

Also, it even only has 106 columns according to AWS Glue, here is the proof:
[image]